# The type ByteArraycontent can not be serialized in web api response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I just want to return a .csv file.

It works with the **HttpResponseMessage** but not with **IHttpActionResult**

Why?

**WORKS**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExportLeads()
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes) };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "test.csv" };
    return result;
}
```

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ExportLeads()
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes) };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "test.csv" };
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}
```

**Error** =>

```
The type "System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent" can not be serialized.
Annotate it with the Attribut "DataContractAttribute"...
```

Comment: Do you specifically want to return a `NegotiatedContentResult`? If not then try `return this.ResponseMessage(result)` as opposed to `return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, result)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, result)` will return a `NegotiatedContentResult`. As such you will need to set up a `ContentNegotiator` and `Formatters` to format the file contents. As you just want to return the raw CSV as a binary array in the content (as per your code returning `HttpResponseMessage`) then  you should use the following:

`return this.ResponseMessage(result)`